# linq-to-sql Query Result to c# Dictionary - How To

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

With c# and LinqToSql I query a database Table and return a single unique record.

**QUESTION:**
How do I place the results of my query into a Dictionary with: 
the Column Names of the database Table as the Dictionary Keys and 
the Column Values of the database Table as the Dictionary Values.

**Note:** I will not always know the name or number of the Table's Column Names

```
Dictionary<string, string> QueryResult = new Dictionary<string, string>

var UniqueRecord = (from tbl DataContext.Table
                                 where tbl.ColumnName1.Equals(Parameter1) 
                                 && tbl.ColumnName2.Equals(Parameter2)
                                 select tbl);
```

//How do I add var UniqueRecord to the Dictionary

==================================================================================

## **I eventually used this**

==================================================================================

```
var UniqueRecord = (from tbl DataContext.Table
                                 where tbl.ColumnName1.Equals(Parameter1) 
                                 && tbl.ColumnName2.Equals(Parameter2)
                                 select tbl);


 foreach(var item in OnlineBezeichnungRekord)
 {
   var properties = item.GetType()
                        .GetProperties()
                        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(item, null).ToString());

   Dictionary<string,string> DictionaryValues = properties;

  }
```

Comment: `UniqueRecord.ToDictionary(.....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering how simple it is to convert a `DataRow` into a `Dictionary` manually, I would not go with `Enumerable.ToDictionary` in your case, and just do loops:

```
Private Function GetDictionaryFromDataRow(dr As DataRow) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
  Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
  For Each col As DataColumn In dr.Table.Columns
    dict.Add(col.ColumnName, dr.Item(col))
  Next
  Return dict
End Function
```

Then just make sure your query returns a `DataRow`, so use `UniqueRecord(0)`.